# javascript text box array and get values and focus on particular field

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="textbox" name="Tue[]" />
<input type="textbox" name="Tue[]" />
<input type="textbox" name="Tue[]" />
<input type="textbox" name="Tue[]" />
```

am entering invalid values in textbox 3, how to alert message and focus particularly into textbox 3

Comment: The input type 'textbox' doesn't exist and there is no such thing as a 'text box array'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the following function to the onblur event of the textbox

```
function validateText(event){
var tar_ele = $(event.target);
if(tar_ele.val() is not valid)
tar_ele.focus();

}

<input type="text" name="Tue[]" onblur="validateText(event)"/>
```

Comment: then u can do event.target.focus()

Comment: `event.target` will not work in IE<9. And again `type="textbox"` is not valid.

Comment: @Kooilnc I have edited the type="textbox" and yes in IE we will have to use event.srcElement

Comment: is there any function like event.target.value