# How get the textbox values in array.....to store in database

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code...

How get the textbox array value to store in database...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var max = 4; //highest number to go to
            var currentIndex = 0;
            function btnClick() {
                if(currentIndex < max){
                    currentIndex++;
                    postClick();
                }
            }
            function Previous(){
                if(currentIndex>0){
                    currentIndex--;
                    postClick();
                }
            }

            function postClick() {//whatever you want to happen goes here
                var sahans = new Array();
                sahans[currentIndex] == d;
                var d = document.getElementById("div");
                d.innerHTML   = "<p><input type='text' name='name"+currentIndex+"[]'>";
                d.innerHTML  += "<p><input type='text' name='topic"+currentIndex+"[]'>";
                document.getElementById("div").style.display = ""; 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1">
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="Previous();" />
                <input type="button" value="Next" onclick="btnClick();" />
                <div id="div"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you need to do. Can you be more clear?can you create a fiddlke on jsfiddle.net

Comment: where is the question? You just posted your code, are we to just do it for you?

Comment: Considering the code and tags of the question, I can only refer you to use localStorage. Please see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript:**

```
function store(form) {
    var input = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var myarray = Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
            myarray[input[i].getAttribute('name')] = input[i].value;
        }
    }
    for (var i in myarray) {
        alert(i + ': ' + myarray[i]);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form onsubmit="store(this); return false">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="topic" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Store in database" />
    </p>
</form>
```

---

**Edit:**

Ok, now I made a full example with AJAX and the actual saving to the database. The AJAX call uses 'POST'. Simply fill in the number of fields that you want in the `max` variable.

**JavaScript:**

```
var max = 10;
var current = 0;
function goto(form, pos) {
    current += pos;
    form.prev.disabled = current <= 0;
    form.next.disabled = current >= max - 1;
    var fields = form.getElementsByTagName('fieldset');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) fields[i].style.display = 'none';
    fields[current].style.display = 'block';
    form['name' + current].focus();
}
function store(form) {
    var input = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var data = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text')
            data += '&' + input[i].getAttribute('name') + '=' + input[i].value;
    }
    data = encodeURI('n=' + max + data);
    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    xhr.open('POST', 'store.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-length', data.length);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseText != '')
                alert(this.responseText);
            else {
                form.submit.value = 'Saved!';
                setTimeout(function() { form.submit.value = 'Save to database' }, 500);
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(data);
}
window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var container = form.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    container.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++)
        container.innerHTML += '<fieldset><legend>Entry ' + (i + 1) + ' / ' + max + '</legend><input type="text" name="name' + i + '" /><br /><input type="text" name="topic' + i + '" /></fieldset>';
    goto(form, 0);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" onsubmit="store(this); return false">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="prev" onclick="goto(this.form, -1)" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" onclick="goto(this.form, +1)" value="Next" />
    </p>
    <div>
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to see this form correctly.</noscript>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Store in database" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Users who have JS disabled will see what's in the `<noscript>` tag, otherwise it's replaced with the fieldsets. Also it's good to make an alternative submit page (submit.php) for users who have JS disabled. Below is store.php, the AJAX submit script.

**PHP** (store.php):

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['n']) || $_POST['n'] < 1) die('Invalid request!');

$fields = array('name', 'topic');
$errors = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['n']; $i++) {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (empty($_POST[$field . $i]))
            $errors .= '- ' . $field . ' ' . ($i + 1) . "\n";
    }
}
if ($errors != '')
    die("Please fill in the following fields:\n" . $errors);

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('mydb', $db);

for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['n']; $i++) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name' . $i]);
    $topic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic' . $i]);
    mysql_query('   INSERT INTO entries (id, name, topic) VALUES (' . $i . ', "' . $name . '", "' . $topic . '")
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = "' . $name . '", topic = "' . $topic . '"
    ') or die('Database error!');
}

mysql_close($db);
?>
```

The output text of this script (if there is an error) is displayed in the JavaScript `alert`.

I hope it's working for you now.

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if this is what you were trying to do.

Comment: You can only save 2 textboxes at a time (`name0` and `topic0` or  `name1` and `topic1` etc.), because only two are displayed. You'll have to change your approach if you want to be able to edit all the textboxes using previous and next buttons and store all of them to the database. If this is what you want I can give an example of that. And also, does your database table have an index field?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I edited my answer, check if it works!

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. I'll update my answer again.

Comment: Why don't you add the fields in the HTML like in my example?

Comment: Hmm, I see. I expected you were writing the textboxes using PHP or something, depending on how many files the user selects. I'm gonna modify my script again.

Comment: I just updated the code. Do you mean you want to display the file names in the `name` fields?

Comment: i have send u my filenames array code: please give me solution how to save the filename in database....also show the name in <div id="filenames></div>" at a time........

Comment: also how to check all textbox filled or not in javascript.......y iam asking if all textbox filled it will go to the another function.....

Comment: midas.....very urgent......pls reply......in my php page                if ($errors == '')
 {echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>fileuploadstart();</SCRIPT>\n";)
 i want all textbox filled by user it will go to fileuploadstart function...........above code i wrote in php...how write in java script page.........

Comment: hi friend.....textboxes did not show in my pop up box.....when i click the next and prev button ....it is showing fields[current] is undefined
[Break On This Error] fields[current].style.display = 'block'; .....i think <fieldset> problem.......

Comment: also showing  Invalid request! in index page...... how to enable JavaScript to see this form correctly

Comment: hi....midas.....reply.......because  in from your above script html code is in my index page.......js is in my additional fs page......so only textboxes did not show.........wat a problem i cant identify.......pls help me........

Comment: midas....please..reply......only two question answer me..........1,how do find all textboxes filled or not in js.   2,only ur script work in single page.......it did not work in seperte page.......so <div>
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to see this form correctly</noscript>
    </div> did not show..but function is running......i will show the textboxes in popup box......so i am asking u......

Comment: hi midas.........very urgent.......please help me........my form <div>
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to see this form correctly.</noscript>
    </div> this did not work................

Comment: midas......... this point is very important..........the max value u had set intially.....but according to my concept after onload the page  set the max value......because max = number of selected files by user....... so your script only possible to run  html and js in single page....otherwise cant run..so div value did not display....................

Comment: i explain u with details.......if user select 10 file so after automatically show the popup box to get the description ....into my popupbox i show two textboxes (per each click )and next & prev buttons also selected file names one by one per each click also with textboxes...... r u clear that how i declare the max value...................

Comment: You can send me an email (address is on my profile). I don't completely understand what you want to do, so send me your website URL or files, so that I can look at it. I'm not going to change my answer again because I'm always guessing what you are trying to do. Try to ask a more specific question next time.

Comment: Yes, I am busy with it. Please be patient.

Comment: ok...midas......u see....(http://jsfiddle.net/sankarss/gAVZ8/)  initially all textbox is showing.....after when i click the next or prev button it will show per each click 2 textboxes........how to solve this problem...........

Answer (score 0):

This would be help ful for you

```
    <input type="textbox" name="Tue[]" />
    <input type="textbox" name="Tue[]" />
    <input type="textbox" name="Tue[]" />
    <input type="textbox" name="Tue[]" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateText(event){
            var tar_ele = $(event.target);
            if(tar_ele.val() is not valid)
                tar_ele.focus();
        }
    </script>


<input type="text" name="Tue[]" onblur="validateText(event)"/>
```

[javascript text box array and get values and focus on particular field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840447/javascript-text-box-array-and-get-values-and-focus-on-particular-field)

Comment: hi.....vikram....how get alltextbox array vale at a time.....to store in a database.....